# linkedin jsapi - people search with keywords ORed not ANDed

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, jsapi

Is any ability to make a search using ORed parameters inside the **keywords**?

For instance, the request below fetching the 1st level connection with ANDed keywords - javascript, extjs, java.

```
            IN.API.PeopleSearch()
                .params({keywords: 'javascript extjs java', facet: 'network,F'})
                .result(displaySearchedProfiles);
```

Looking for a way to use OR between the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like LinkedIn not provide ability to control queering string.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I got the same issue, but I seen that https://apigee.com service can retrieve everything. May be  they uses another kind of api

Anyway thanks for your question